# Change the legend in Google's Geochart visualization api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

Is there any way to customize the legend shown here:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart.html

I am trying to more stuff to the legend, change its location etc.

I looked through their docs but couldn't find the anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From Google's API chart guide - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?csw=1#Configuration_Options

If I understand correctly, when passing options to the geo chart using the `legend` key, you can supply it with style data to enforce how it appears. Ie -

```
{
   textStyle: {
      color: 'blue', fontSize: 16
   }
}
```

as prescribed by Google in the above link.